# Resharper C++ syntax highlighting fails

Tags: c++, resharper

Resharper C++'s syntax highlighting always fails if I include beast/http.hpp from https://github.com/vinniefalco/Beast. If I include that file suddenly only keywords, preprocessor directives and strings are syntax highlighted. Auto completion still works and I also still have codeannotations and receive inspection warnings. Is there anything I can do to get syntax highlighting back online?

Comment: Which R++ release are you using? I can't reproduce using the 2016.1 release. Can you please create a request in R++'s issue tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project:%20%7BReSharper%20C%2B%2B%7D) and attach an example solution where this problem occurs?

Comment: here there issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-17500